# Run python from HTML

Tags: python, html, button, brython

I need to run some python code when HTML button click,
I try this code but when I clicked the button nothing happened.
This is my code:
'''
<!doctype html>

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.9.0/brython.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="brython()">

    <script type="text/python">
        def change_image():
            from browser import document, html
            document["image"].clear()
            document["image"] <= html.IMG(src="flowers.jpg")

        document["next"].bind("click", change_image)

    </script>
    <img id="image" src="image.png">
    <input id="next" type="button" value="next state"/>


</body>

</html>
```

'''
What is my problem??

Comment: What makes you think your browser supports python?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I used brython for this, you can read about this here https://brython.info/static_tutorial/en/index.html

Comment: Then you should have tagged brython and not python.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a problem.Change it as follows

```
<script type="text/python">

from browser import document, html #Use the form outside the function
def change_image(item):
    document["image"].clear()
    document["image"].src="flowers.jpg" #change attributes

document["next"].bind("click", change_image)

</script>
```

**Full code**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.9.0/brython.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="brython()">
    <script type="text/python">

from browser import document, html
def change_image(item):
    document["image"].clear()
    document["image"].src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg"

document["next"].bind("click", change_image)

    </script>

    <img width=200 id="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <input id="next" type="button" value="next state"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried, but it did not help. Still nothing is happening...

Comment: @pddh Check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLGTIT4SKMYA)

Comment: It works, so what could be the reason it does not work on my computer with my pictures?

Comment: @pddh Do you see an error in your browser console?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem, you can see in my code that my function did not receive any event and that was the problem...